# RDP sessions freezes when I try to login

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, remote-desktop

I setup RDP with my home PC. I use a standard linksys WRT54g router and setup port forwarding.

I can ping my PC with no issues. I RDP to it and then when I logon it freezes and I can go longer ping my router. Any suggestions? This happened 3 times.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wired or wireless? Had similar issues when I had intermittent packet loss connected over WiFi. Changed to Ethernet and it was fine.

In addition, have you forwarded correct ports on router and tried disabling the firewall on the PC?

Comment: It is wireless. Firewall is disabled. Port is 3389.